# Should TForm.ManualDock call onFormShow?

Tags: delphi, events, event-handling, docking

As I typed this question I realize that it probably should.

Docking a form to a TPageControl calls FormShow when form.Create() is called and when form.ManualDock(pagecontrol,pagecontrol.alClient) is called.

Un-docking the form also calls show and I assume this is because the form is actually 'reset' when you dock/undock?

If this is as designed I'll just refactor the code I dont want to fire there to onCreate (unless that is bad design).

Comment: FormShow will also be called after a manual Form.Hide; Form.Show; too. The way you describe it, you only want the code to run once, so FormCreate would be a better place anyway. Even if you never hide your form, other programs can hide your forms too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If should or not is more philosophical than technical question. The [`TForm.OnShow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TForm.OnShow) event is fired by performing control message [`CM_DOCKCLIENT`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TCMDockClient) which is used also by the [`ManualDock`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.ManualDock) function. Internally this message calls the [`CM_SHOWINGCHANGED`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls#Constants) what fires the event itself.

In the following example I will use two forms, Form1 (with a page control and a button) and Form2 (empty and dockable). I presume that both are auto created.

The following code is a proof that the [`OnShow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TForm.OnShow) event is fired by the [`CM_DOCKCLIENT`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TCMDockClient) control message. Clicking on the button, the [`CM_DOCKCLIENT`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TCMDockClient) message is performed and Form2's [`OnShow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TForm.OnShow) event is fired.

Code for Form1

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DockObject: TDragDockObject;
begin
  DockObject := TDragDockObject.Create(Form2);
  try
    // sending the CM_DOCKCLIENT message internally performs also the
    // CM_SHOWINGCHANGED message which triggers the TForm.OnShow event
    PageControl1.Perform(CM_DOCKCLIENT, WPARAM(DockObject), LPARAM(SmallPoint(0, 0)));
  finally
    DockObject.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And Form2 has only the [`OnShow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TForm.OnShow) event handler

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('FormShow');
end;
```

An easy workaround is not to dock the Form2 manually by its own (in the [`OnShow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TForm.OnShow) event) but dock it by the creator or let's say by the form which displays it. In my previous example I've displayed the Form2 in the Form1.OnShow event, so I can easily dock it manually there.

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show;
  Form2.ManualDock(PageControl1);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // no manual docking of this form by itself
end;
```

Comment: Thanks - I just tossed what I needed in OnCreate.